# Sum array elements in Mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection with `c` array inside each document

```
{
  {
    id: 1,
    k: 2.2,
    type: "dog",
    c: [ {parentId:1, p:2.2}, {parentId:1, p:1.4} ]
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    k: 4.3,
    type:"cat",
    c: [ {parentId:2, p:5.2}, {parentId:2, p:4.5} ]
  }
}
```

`parentId` inside each subdocument in `c` is id of containing document.

I want to group all docs by `type` and in each group know sum of `k` and sum of all `p` in all arrays of the group.

Currently I do summation of `k` in the group stage but summation of `p` in the result array in the application. I want to do summation of `p` in DB!

This is what I do currently:

```
db.myCol.aggregate([

{ 
  $group: {
    _id: { type: '$type'},
    k: {$sum: '$k'}, // sum k values, very easy!
    // p: {$sum: '$c.0.p'} <==== Does not work, too
    c: {$addToSet: '$c'} // add to each group all c arrays of group's members
  }   
}
], function(err, res) {
   // go over c-arrays and sum p values
   var accP = 0; // accumulator for p values
   for ( var i=0; i<res.length; i++ ) {
     var c = res[i].c;
     for (var j=0;j<c.length; j++) {
       var c2 = c[j];
       for ( var k=0; k<c2.length; k++) { // finally got to objects c array
          accP += c2[k].p;
       }
     }
     res[i].c = accP; // replace array with accumulated p value
   }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to first [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) your documents by "type", use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) accumulator operator to return the sum of "k"  and use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) which returns a 2D array of "c". Now you need two ["$unwind"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) stage where you denormalize the "c" 2D array. Your last stage in the pipeline is another [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage where you calculate the sum of "p" using "dot notation"

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$group': {
        '_id': '$type', 
        'k': { '$sum': '$k' }, 'c': { '$push': '$c' } 
    } }, 
    { '$unwind': '$c' }, 
    { '$unwind': '$c' },
    { '$group': { 
        '_id': '$_id', 
        'k': { '$first': '$k' }, 
        'c': { '$sum': '$c.p' }
    }}
])
```

Which yields:

```js
{ "_id" : "dog", "k" : 2.2, "c" : 3.6 }
{ "_id" : "cat", "k" : 4.3, "c" : 9.7 }
```

---

> [Starting in version 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/#accumulator-expression-availability), the following accumulator expressions, previously only available in the `$group` stage, are now also available in the `$project` stage.

Which means that we can take advantage of that and use the `$sum` accumulator operator in [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project). Of course the `$map` operator returns an array of "p" for each document.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$project': { 
        'type': 1, 
        'k': 1, 
        'c': { 
            '$sum': {
                '$map': { 
                    'input': '$c', 
                    'as': 'subc', 
                    'in': '$$subc.p'
                }
            }
        }
    }}, 
    { '$group': { 
        '_id': '$type', 
        'k': { '$sum': '$k' }, 
        'c': { '$sum': '$c' }
    }}
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "_id" : "cat", "k" : 4.3, "c" : 9.7 }
{ "_id" : "dog", "k" : 2.2, "c" : 3.6 }
```