# MongoDB sum arrays from multiple documents on a per-element basis

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document structure (simplified for this example)

```js
{
  _id : ObjectId("sdfsdf"),
  result : [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
},
{
  _id : ObjectId("asdref"),
  result : [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
}
```

I want to get the sum of those `result` arrays, but not a total sum, instead a new array corresponding to the sum of the original arrays on an element basis, i.e.

```js
result : [3, 7, 11, 15, 19]
```

I have searched through the myriad questions here and a few come close (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118631/sum-array-elements-in-mongodb-aggregation), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319799/mongodb-aggregation-with-sum-of-array-values), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187453/mongodb-aggregate-sum-each-key-on-a-subdocument)), but I can't quite get there.

I can get the sum of each array fine

```
aggregate(
    [
      {
        "$unwind" : "$result"
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "results" : { "$sum" : "$result"}
          }
      }
    ]
)
```

which gives me

```js
[ { _id: sdfsdf, results: 25 },
  { _id: asdref, results: 30 } ]
```

but I can't figure out how to get the sum of each element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [includeArrayIndex](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#includearrayindex-and-preservenullandemptyarrays) if you have 3.2 or newer MongoDb.

Then you should change `$unwind`.

Your code should be like this:

```
.aggregate(
    [
      {
        "$unwind" :  { path: "$result", includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex" }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "$arrayIndex",
          "results" : { "$sum" : "$result"}
          }
      },
      { 
        $sort: { "_id": 1}
      },
      {
        "$group":{
          "_id": null,
          "results":{"$push":"$results"}
          } 
      },
      {
        "$project": {"_id":0,"results":1}
      }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Sort of works. But instead of creating a single array, it simply lists the sums one by one eg. "NumberLong(3), "results: 15"

Comment: I have updated answer for projection can you test it again ?

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):11:2

Comment: Ok I fixed the syntax can you try again ?

Comment: This sums everything together eg. "results": [ 55 ]

Comment: Ok in second group we shouldn't group by arrayindex I changed it to null.

Comment: No, this isn't what I want. This sums each array, and then sums all those together too, producing `[ { results: [55 ] } ]`

Comment: Ok first grouping "arrayIndex" it should be "$arrayIndex". Sory guys I don't have place for test it. I have changed it on answer.

Comment: Ok changing `arrayIndex` to `$arrayIndex` seems to be doing what I want, except the ordering isn't preserved so `doc1.result[0] + doc2.result[0] != results[0]`

Comment: We should add sorting before second grouping. I have added to answer.

Comment: If I needed to first group docs with a matching field, what stage of the pipeline should I put that? So say each doc had another field `even: true` and I wanted to just group the docs with that

Comment: You should add this matching top of aggregation before unwind.

Comment: Actually it works also if I include it in the group section after unwind

Comment: It works. When you use match first your result set becomes smaller. Then you are grouping or unwind this small set instead of big one. So if you use first it's better for performance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103859/discussion-between-philip-obrien-and-maderkan).

Comment: I've experimented with this on a huge amount of data and the grouping required too much RAM. Something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternate approach to this, but mileage may vary on how practical it is considering that a different approach would involve using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) to create an "array of arrays" and then applying [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) as introduced in MongoDB 3.4 to [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) those array elements into a single array result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "result": { "$push": "$result" }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "result": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$result",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": {
          "$map": {
            "input": { 
              "$zip": {
                "inputs": [ "$$this", "$$value" ],
                "useLongestLength": true
              }
            },
            "as": "el",
            "in": { "$sum": "$$el" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

The real trick there is in the `"input"` to [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) we use the [`$zip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) operation which creates a transposed list of arrays "pairwise" for the two array inputs.

In a first iteration this takes the empty array as supplied to [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) and would return the "zipped" output with consideration to the first object found as in:

```
[ [0,1], [0,3], [0,5], [0,7], [0,9] ]
```

So the `useLongestLength` would substitute the empty array with `0` values out to the the length of the current array and "zip" them together as above.

Processing with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), each element is subject to [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) which "reduces" the returned results as:

```
[ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ]
```

On the second iteration, the next entry in the "array of arrays" would be picked up and processed by [`$zip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) along with the previous "reduced" content as:

```
[ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10] ]
```

Which is then subject to the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) for each element using [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) again to produce:

```
[ 3, 7, 11, 15, 19 ]
```

And since there were only two arrays pushed into the "array of arrays" that is the end of the operation, and the final result. But otherwise the [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) would keep iterating until all array elements of the input were processed.

---

So in some cases this would be the more performant option and what you should be using. But it is noted that particularly when using a `null` for [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) you are asking "every" document to [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) content into an array for the result.

This could be a cause of breaking the BSON Limit in extreme cases, and therefore when aggregating positional array content over large results, it is probably best to use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) with the `includeArrayIndex` option instead.

Or indeed actually take a good look at the process, where in particular if the "positional array" in question is actually the result of some other "aggregation operation", then you should rather be looking at the previous pipeline stages that were used to create the "positional array". And then consider that if you wanted those positions "aggregated further" to new totals, then you should in fact do that "before" the positional result was obtained.